# Magento 1.9.3 reindex notification in admin won't disappear

Tags: indexing, magento1.9.3

All reindexing have been done and shows green(Ready) status.

Re-indexing has done manually in admin panel and tried to it with SSH, but still, it shows re.indexing required message, just wondering is it a problem or why it pops up every time!

Thanks!
[image]